# How to force dataProxy call in form editing if editurl is set in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqGrid is defined using code below. editurl is used for inline edit.
dataProxy is used to upload images in form edit.

However dataProxy is not called if save button is pressed in form edit.
How to force dataProxy to be called or other way to allow to upload images in jqGrid column ?

```
$grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        url: '/GetData',
        editurl: '/Edit',
... 
});


$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#grid_toppager", { 
            search:  true,
            del: true,
            add: true,
            view: true,
            edit: true
          }, 

        {
    url: null,
    dataProxy : function(opt, args) { 
      alert('Why this box does not appear on form save if jqgrid editurl is set'); 
      },

    beforeInitData: function () {
       var
         colm = $grid.jqGrid('getColProp', '_image'),
         selRowId = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
      colm.editoptions.src = '/GetImage?id=' + selRowId;

    },
   closeAfterEdit: true,
   reloadAfterSubmit: true,
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe the goal of the usage of `dataProxy`, but if you really need to use the feature you should bu following:

- you should define `dataProxy` as callback of jqGrid. You can use `$.extend` to change `$.jgrid.defaults`.
- either `url` for Add/Edit or Delete operation should be `null` or you should set `useDataProxy` option of `editGridRow` or `delGridRow` to `true` explicitly (for example to overwrite `editurl` which are not `null`).

So in your case you should just move `dataProxy` from the list of Edit dialog to the list of jqGrid options.

Comment: The goal of using data proxy is to allow to upload images in jqgrid. Same jqGrid page is used to edit lot of tables. if $.extend is used to define dataproxy, how to pass extra parameter (table name) to dataproxy?

Comment: @Andrus: I'm not sure that I understand you correct. `dataProxy` function will be called in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L812) and has as third parameter the table name with the prefix `"set_"`. You can use the fact. Alternatively you can use `editData` parameter to extend `postData` information send by form editing. The  `postData` will be the part of the object which is the second parameter of `dataProxy`.