# dilemna with jqgrid and ajaxfileupload

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid and ajaxFileUpload.js script in order to pass parameters and files to a php script. The structure of the code is like this:

```
 ...  
 url:url_1.php,  
 beforeSubmit: function (postdata,formid)  
   {  
      $.ajaxFileUpload (  
         {  
             url: url_2.php,  
             ...  
             success:  
             error:    
         }), 
      return[true,""];  
   }, 
afterSubmit: function(reponse,postdata)  
   {
      ...  
      return [true,'',''];
   }
```

I have a dilemna:
According to the jqgrid behaviour, url_2.php is called, then url_1.php.
url_2.php handles the data (parameters + file), url_1.php handles nothing.
url_2.php could return an error or message (e.g "already exist") but, the errors are displayed in the form by the aftersubmit event, and this event receives error from url_1.php !!!
I suppose that I am obliged to put the ajaxfileupload in the beforesubmit event !!!
Any ideas to solve this dilemna ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery form plugin and jqGrid dataProxy method instead.

```
    useDataProxy: true,
    dataProxy :  function (opts, act) {  

    opts.iframe = true;
    var $form = $('#FrmGrid_' + $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'id'));
    //Prevent non-file inputs double serialization
    var ele = $form.find('INPUT,TEXTAREA,SELECT').not(':file');
    ele.each(function () {
        $(this).data('name', $(this).attr('name'));
        $(this).removeAttr('name');
    });

    //Send only previously generated data + files
    $form.ajaxSubmit(opts);
    //Set names back after form being submitted
    setTimeout(function () {
        ele.each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).data('name'));
        });
    }, 200);
};
```

For example http://jqgrid-php.net file  fileUpload class uses this. This is described in [How to force dataProxy call in form editing if editurl is set in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473879/how-to-force-dataproxy-call-in-form-editing-if-editurl-is-set-in-jqgrid) also.

Comment: dataproxy is not in the jqgrid wiki !

Comment: Why the setTimeout at the end ?